# Create a function $f(x,y)$ with critical points satisfying $x^2+y^2=1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

I have no idea where to start.

I might be onto something using polar coordinates $\sin \theta$ and $\cos \theta$ but adding an extra variable $\theta$ doesn't help create a 2 variable function $f(x,y)$

Does  "critical points satisfying $x^2+y^2=1$" mean
$$0=f_x=f_y=x^2+y^2-1$$

Would appreciate any help or hint.

Comment: By the way, Clairaut's Theorem about equality of mixed partials immediately implies that "$f_x=f_y=x^2+y^2-1$" is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can tell you that the word *satisfy*, in that context, means that when you find the critical points and plug them into the equation, it needs to "work". For example, $\sqrt{2}$ "satisfies" the equation $x^2 = 2$. Suppose you could cook yourself up a function whose only critical points were (1,0) and (0,1). That would satisfy your constraint.

So to answer your question, no, it does *not* mean that the partial derivatives equal that equation. It does mean that the points $(x,y)$ at which the gradient equals 0, or is undefined, must satisfy the equation.

Here is a function that I believe works:

$f(x,y) = \sqrt{1 - \left(1 - \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2}$

(it's the upper half of a torus)

Answer (score 0):

Consider the equations in polar coordinate:

\begin{eqnarray*}
r^\prime=1-r\\
\theta^\prime=0
\end{eqnarray*}

and transform into Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Sorry how would that turn out for a function f(x,y) ?

Answer (score 0):

Certain details should be specified. It has already been mentioned here that if critical points of $f$ (denote the set of these points by $C$) satisfy the equation $x^2+y^2=1$ then not all points of the unit circle $S=\{(x,y): \, x^2+y^2=1\}$ should be critical. An appropriate example is $f(x,y)\equiv (x-1)^2+y^2.$

If you want $C$ to coincide with $S$ take $f(x,y)\equiv(x^2+y^2-1)^2$ assuming that the domain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}^2\setminus\{(0,0)\}.$ Note, that you cannot construct a differentiable function satisfying $S=C$ without excluding the points of the open disk $D=\{(x,y): \, x^2+y^2<1\}$ from the domain. Indeed, if there exists a differentiable function $f$ whose domain contains $S \cup D$ and equality $C=S$ holds then $f$ is constant on $S,$ since the derivative of $f$ along the curve $S$ is zero. The Weierstrass extreme value theorem implies that $f$ has a point of local extremum in $D.$ Hence, $C\neq S$ and we obtain a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine the surface plot of such a thing. If the critical points are local minima, it needs to look like someone tossed a heavy iron ring onto a memory foam mattress. Except that would also leave a critical point in the inside of the ring, so you have to do something like let the curve spike to infinity inside.

Rotating $z=f(x)=(\ln(x))^2$ about the $z$-axis should work. That means $$f(x,y)=\left(\ln\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\right)^2$$

I'll leave it to you to work out $f_x$ and $f_y$ in this example, but they are not equal to each other and not equal to $x^2+y^2-1$. Rather, "$f_x=0$" is equivalent to "either $x^2+y^2-1=0$ or $x=0$". And "$f_y=0$" is equivalent to "either $x^2+y^2-1=0$ or $y=0$". The combination $x=0$ and $y=0$ is not considered since that is not in the domain by design. The end result is that $f_x=f_y=0$ is equivalent to $x^2+y^2-1=0$ for all $(x,y)$ in $f$'s domain.